# The url in json contains backslashes

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I was just wondering why my wcf rest returns json which contains backslahses in the url. it is as below:

```
https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/reiaustralia\/1fc00dfab25044ecb31e4882121b535e\/jpg\/download.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTDESL6TBRAVM4Q&Expires=1380692091&Signature=MduuaUAjQRisadtM%2FDuVDemexLY%3D
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Forward slashes can be escaped with a backslash in JSON, but they don't have to be. So either one of the following:

```
{"url":"http://www.example.com/"}
or
{"url":"http\/\/www.example.com\/"}
```

Will parse into an object which has a `url` property whose string value is `http://www.example.com/`.

Some technologies will escape out the slashes when generating JSON, and some won't. PHP, for example, has an option called [JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) which lets you control whether or not to escape your slashes.

You can get see the various escape characters from the [json.org](http://json.org/) home page in the "string" section.

Answer (score 1):

Because // (double slash) in javascript means comment and /{string}/ (string inside slash) is mean regula expression.

So. To keep correct value in json it have to put \ (back slash) in front of / (slash).

Comment: This is JSON, not javascript. There are no comments or regular expressions inside of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

They are just escape characters, and when u consume the string in your application it would just be fine

Comment: if u put this in the web browser, it does not work.https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/reiaustralia\/1fc00dfab25044ecb31e4882121b535e\/jpg\/download.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTDESL6TBRAVM4Q&Expires=1380692866&Signature=%2BRNjuMCNYtI79A1DZ74mqLQnWRo%3D