# Escape character in WCF service calls

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wcf

I am implementing WCF Rest Service for  a mobile app.

This is one of the property of return object which I get on response of a service call:

```
"flagURL":"http:\/\/localhost\/testservice\/img\/CountryFlags\/Ireland.png"
```

When I  debug the code there is no escape character '/',and json looks like this

```
"flagURL":"http:\\localhost\testservice\img\CountryFlags\Ireland.png"
```

How does the service add an escape character to above property ? What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The url in json contains backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130605/the-url-in-json-contains-backslashes)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is getting double-serialized. (The extra backslashes in the JSON are symptomatic of this.) To make it work, you need to ensure that the output is only serialized once.

there is a simple solution for that. just return `stream` except `string`:

```
  public stream checkSymbolExistJson(string pSymbol)
  {
        Person p    = new Person();
        p.name      = pSymbol;
        p.age       = 15;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
  }
```